# How do you make a form title dynamically change with a button click?

Tags: c#, .net

I know this is how to change the text in a Label:

```
namespace Go_Team
{
    public partial class TitleBar : Form
    {
        public TitleBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GoTeamBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            //Change Name of HelloWorldLbl to "Atlanta Braves!"
        {
            HelloWorldLbl.Text = "Atlanta Braves!";                
        }

        private void GoTeamBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //Change Name of title bar to "Atlanta Braves!"
        {
            This.Text = "Atlanta Braves!";
        }
    }
}
```

How do I change the text in the titlebar of the form? I already have a button that is linked to a label. I need one button to adjust the name of a label and the name of the title bar.

Comment: Any chance you could you add some more words to turn this into a question? At the moment it reads like youre stating how to change the text of a button

Comment: Can someone show me how to make a Form Title dynamically change with a button click?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You may also which to peruse [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Answer (score 1):

```
private void GoTeamBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelloWorldLbl.Text = "Atlanta Braves!";
    this.Text = "Atlanta Braves!"; //you're in a Form. "this" refers to the form
}
```

Comment: Im trying to change the name of the Form to "Atlanta Braves!" when clicking this button. do i not have to add another private void? Do I have to specify anything else? thanks. im a new c# student

Comment: @HereticMonkey Indeed.. and also from many pages on the site: "[Adrian Bermudez] is a new contributor.. be nice" - there are many ways to tackle a problem. Sometimes I bash em with the rule book, I promise :)

Comment: I apologize for being a noob! Thank You, In the future I will read through that.

Comment: @AdrianBermudez No problem! we all started somewhere. I still ask questions some people here would think are noob, I'm sure!

Comment: I went ahead and edited my question. Thank you for the help. Ive been bashing my head into my Visual C# book for two hours now.

Comment: Can you check the code I have attached for me again? Is that how you format the form title change?

Comment: C# is case sensitive. `This` is not the same as `this`. You also cannot declare two methods with identical names and parameter lists. Just put both statements in one method. I edited to show the exact thing you must have

Comment: I appreciate you.